# What is the best phrasing for "starting price" of a product on ecommerce site?

Tags: e-commerce, copywriting, pricing

On an ecommerce site, I'm showing products and a starting price. Should I say:
1. "As low as $50"
2. "Starting at $50"
3. "From $50"
4. "$50 and up"
5. other?!

Please see [mockup with 4 examples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdPs2.jpg) for clarification

Comment: It depends on your definition of "best". But if your goal is to maximize conversion, @alanvitek's deferral to Amazon's relentless A/B testing seems like the right call. (But you shouldn't be afraid to test in your own product's context as well.)

Comment: I got feedback from several other friends in the biz and got equal votes for each answer. Bottom line is I think different people would see those phrases differently so there is no right answer. I was more or less just looking for opinion. Testing will be done over the next several months. I'll update this question at some point in the future with some results.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon uses "from" in this context: [image]

**EDIT**

Note that this is not a starting price, but a group of similar products with different prices.

Comment: I generally don't like to use the "well Amazon does it this way" approach, but it really is the most concise way to put it. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: Anecdotal evidence should not be used to support an answer. It's great that you provided an example though.

Comment: @usingtheinternet - I apologize as I did not intend for my answer to come across in that way. I have edited it accordingly